# Android: Update text in notification without resetting animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications

I'm trying to implement a notification for my music app. It's comprised of play/pause and next buttons, and a TextView with marquee enabled so that the song title scrolls. When I try to change the play/pause buttons icon, the marquee text resets.

Here's my notification layout file:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/perm_group_audio_settings"
        android:id="@+id/album_art"
        android:background="#00000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/album_art"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:id="@+id/song_name">
        <requestFocus/>
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/album_art"
        android:layout_below="@+id/song_name"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/player_stop"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_media_stop"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/player_pause"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_media_pause"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/player_next"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_media_next"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the notification class:

```
    public class MediaPlayerNotification extends Notification {
    private Context context;

    private NotificationManager m_manager;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder m_builder;
    private RemoteViews m_view;
    private Notification m_notification;

    public MediaPlayerNotification(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        m_builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(NOTIFICATION_TITLE)
                .setSmallIcon(NOTIFICATION_ICON)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

        m_view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_player);
        m_view.setImageViewResource(R.id.player_stop, ICON_STOP);
        m_view.setImageViewResource(R.id.player_pause, ICON_PAUSE);
        m_view.setImageViewResource(R.id.player_next, ICON_NEXT);

        m_builder.setContent(m_view);

        m_notification = m_builder.build();
        m_manager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        m_manager.notify(2, m_notification);
    }

    public void setPausePlayIcon(int iconId) {
        m_view.setImageViewResource(R.id.player_pause, iconId);
        m_manager.notify(2, m_notification);
    }
    public void setNowPlaying(String name) {
        m_view.setTextViewText(R.id.song_name, name);
        m_manager.notify(2, m_notification);
    }
}
```

`setPausePlayIcon()` works exactly as expected and changes the icon, but my TextView resets it's position. Is there any way to change the icon without resetting the entire layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void setPausePlayIcon(int iconId) {
    m_view.setImageViewResource(R.id.player_pause, iconId);
    m_builder.setContent(m_view);
    m_manager.notify(2, m_builder.build());
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything :(

Comment: A Note 4 running 5.0.1. Just to clarify, the buttons change correctly, but calling `setPausePlayIcon()` also resets the 'scrolling' of my TextView. I'd like the scrolling to be smooth and uninterrupted.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the question. What about creating a custom textview that manage the scroll? I mean, when you refresh the notification the current position of the text (in the old notification) is taken and used to set the position of the textview in the new notification.

Comment: Ah yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! I'm not sure how you'd go about passing the position on to the new Notification though. Maybe a singleton?